# Linux account locked due to failed logins

Tags: linux, ubuntu, login, password-recovery, passwd

i hope someone could help me

while trying login to my Ubuntu machine with my user i'm getting "account locked due to 29 failed"

i logged in with recovery mode and now i'm root 
but i can't change any "Pam_tally" configuration because of the recovery mode restrictions.

how can this be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Try remounting the root disk as read-write when in recovery

```
mount / -o remount,rw
```

This will allow you to modify the filesystem and remove the restrictions.

Comment: i did, what should i do now?

Comment: I don't know - I've never used pam_tally.   I'm guessing you will want to edit /etc/nsswitch.conf to remove reference to pam_tally or modify /etc/pam.d/system-auth.    Looking at http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/rhel-centos-fedora-linux-log-failed-login.html though, it would appear to me  that, as root, you could probably reset the login counter simply by using the command faillog -r -u USERNAME  - you don't even need to boot to recovery to do this !